# Opening, Editing, and Saving a .CSV inside a Java program

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, jfilechooser

I'm supposed to create a program that displays an editable CSV in a spreadsheet format, then pulls and appends information from an LDAP source into said spreadsheet and saves it. As it is a lot to handle right off the bat, I'm taking it in small chunks at a time.

Not even going to bother with the LDAP bits yet, I just want to get the Load > Edit > Save bits to work for now.

I figure that if I play around with opening, displaying, and saving .TXT files first I can easily transfer what I learn to later when I implement the .CSV portion. However, I am having difficulties making the Save portion work right (read: at all), and I got a bit of help from reading other posts on here, so I figured I'd ask.

Note: the Oracle Java tute for JFileChooser doesn't cover saving except to barely touch on how to start implementing it, not how it actually functions.

a link to my code:
http://pastebin.com/tWnYrwgM

The code I need the most help with currently:

```
private void SaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
//TODO
}
```

I don't have anything in there currently because I never actually got anything to work when I Built, Ran, or Debugged the project when I did have code there.

I guess what I am trying to say is that I am having trouble writing to file.

Comment: `JFileChooser` isn't really meant to do any saving, it's meant to, well, choose a file – that is, tell you which file path the user picked. It's up to you to open it using regular Java IO and write stuff into it.

Comment: Have you checked out Apache POI?

Comment: Your question as is is a little vague, you should probably figure out what specific step you need to do first and ask about that.

Comment: CSV files aren't as simple as they look, use a well established library to manipulate them, writing a CSV parser yourself will be wasted time and resources for something that only half works.

Comment: Well, I feel like I might be in over my head; at least I'm still interned here until the project is completed! The reason behind using the CSV file system is (according to my boss) so that the client may then view and manage the output file in MSExcel. If there is an easier solution, I am all ears!

Comment: @user1552151 CSV is much much easier to deal with than POI and the native formats.

Comment: Also, stressing just how newbie you are doesn't belong in the question, definitely not at the start because it ruins the preview on the front page, and doesn't really get you out of having to post specific questions. Now, was there something about the file chooser tutorial you didn't understand? Or are you having problems with writing into a file? Or formatting the CSV? If the answer is "all of the above", start with the first step then post separate questions with more informationwhen you hit the next problem.

Comment: I am having problems with the writing to file portion, and I'll get to the CSV portion later. The actual file opening works fine though!

Comment: @ccreason Great! What problems are those? Surely you can tell us more than "okay what goes here".

Comment: Well (as you pointed out) JFileChooser doesn't handle the saving of data. But when I try to implement JFileWriter inside of showSaveDialog NetBeans tosses out some errors. I just reread Angelos' edit so I'll brb after messing with it.

Comment: Alright his code works! Now to start reading up on CSV libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this would be a sample implementation of what you need to do.
Be aware that while this works for basic situations it is not enough. Using an established CSV Library will do much better this is just for educational purpose.

```
JTable myTable; 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        TableModel model = myTable.getModel(); // the table model contains all the data. Read its JavaDoc API it is enlightend when you work with JTables and you can do lots of neat stuff with it.
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        if(fc.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { // no save when the user canceled.
            File target = fc.getSelectedFile();
            FileWriter fWri = new FileWriter(target); // this will create the file, but not any parent directories that might not exist. If there are parent directories that don't exist, this line will throw a FileNotFoundException.
            for(int ii = 0; ii < model.getRowCount(); ii++) {
                StringBuilder lineValue = new StringBuilder();
                for(int jj = 0; ii < model.getColumnCount(); jj++) {
                    lineValue.append(model.getValueAt(ii, jj));
                    lineValue.append(",");
                }
                lineValue.substring(0, lineValue.length() -1); // cut away the last ,
                fWri.write(lineValue + "\r\n"); // the RFC suggests CRLF, but don't be surprised when you get a CSV from somewhere that has only LF or something. Its because of lines like this that you want a library handle it for you.
            }
            fWri.flush();// in fact, this and the next line should go to a 'finally' block. Read about correct and clean file writing to learn more.
            fWri.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
         // file not found, cant be written to, etc. You handle it here.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really use a CSV library for the formatting unless you're absolutely certain you don't need quoting or support for the Excel format.

Comment: @millimoose Yes, but for understanding on how things work its better to implement it (at least in a trivial form) once for yourself. As the OP is an intern it seems important to me that some learning happens :)

Comment: I'd much prefer they write correct code rather than broken naive hacks that will have to be fixed later. (Although I might be projecting from experiences with the all of one intern I've ever tutored.) If you want to learn how to write CSV, you should learn how to do it right and hit [the spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: @ccreason There you go, a very simple example of how that works. Read it, understand it, delete it and write it for yourself again. Then after you understood what is done here, read chapter one and to of the spec (as referenced by @millimoose) understand them as well. (I think coming this far will take about some 4- 8 hours, its not so bad) Then go look out for a decent CSV library and use it.

Comment: @millimoose That depends on the perspective, from the interns point of view learning is more important than productiveness. But I included your advice above so anyone who reads this should be aware that using a library is the better approach after all.

Comment: It's not that I'm against doing something for the sake of the learning experience. I'm against doing so without being aware that in practice, handrolling something (unless you know what you're doing) is a bad idea, and that goes double if you're interfacing with other software. You wouldn't write a HTTP library by eyeballing the output of Wireshark after all.

Comment: @millimoose Yes. I'm completely with you.

Comment: Alright his code works! Now to start reading up on CSV libraries.